# Multiple Projects in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am trying to get all my JavaScript projects in one frame-instance of WebStorm. The reasons for this are good:

- I can refactor across all projects
- I can find usages across all projects

Up until now we have had to open/reopen each project, and just hope that when we change something in project A it won't have an effect in project B. Unfortunately as the number of projects have grown, we have been getting so many errors because we can't safely refactor or 'see' the effects of a change we want to make.

The WebStorm people say that you can just add more content roots, and a 'content root' can be seen like a project.

Fine. But that still means you can only have one deployment configuration.

I'll explain :

I have two projects **projectA** and **projectB**. They both live on the web server at **/projectA** and **/projectB** respectively. They both use a common project called **/ProjectCommon** that needs to be deployed to ***BOTH*** /projectA and /projectB respectively.

If I set up the mappings like this :

[image]

I get an error message, or exclamation marks. The deploy of the ProjectCommon works only on the first instance it comes across (ie. it never deploys to my projectB).

This is incredibly frustrating because it seems like I almost got to multi-project functionality in WebStorm, but now we have to go back to single windows for each project... opening ....re-opening ... * sigh *

Anyone have an idea where you can have a multi-project setup in Webstorm with deployment capabilities? Eclipse can do it, so I don't see why WebStorm can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not currently possible to have the same local path mapped to multiple deployment paths. Please vote for [WI-5839](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5839)